# Error Executing javascript using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, htmlunit

I am trying to execute a JavaScript on the following URL: `http://steamcommunity.com/id/bobcatchris/inventory#730`. I can do it using google chrome by opening console by pressing ctrl+shift+j and pasting the following script:

```
var list = []; 
var size = Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory).size();    
var counter = 0;
while (counter < size) {
 list.push(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory[Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory)[counter]].market_name);
 counter +=1;
}
```

It returns: 150
Then in the next line, i write: `>list`
and it returns an array of length 150.

When i try to do it in `HtmlUnit` as:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WebClient webClient=new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        HtmlPage page=webClient.getPage("http://steamcommunity.com/id/bobcatchris/inventory#730");
        String script="var list = [];\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "var size = Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory).size();\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "var counter = 0;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "while (counter < size) {\n" +
                " list.push(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory[Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory)[counter]].market_name);\n" +
                " counter +=1;\n" +
                "}";
        Object result = page.executeJavaScript(script).getJavaScriptResult();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[4] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[injected script] message=[TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (injected script#4)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (injected script#4)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:959)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:927)
    at Scraper.main(Scraper.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (injected script#4)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3618)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.ensureScriptable(ScriptableObject.java:2095)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeObject.execIdCall(NativeObject.java:287)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:89)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 12 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (injected script#4)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3618)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.ensureScriptable(ScriptableObject.java:2095)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeObject.execIdCall(NativeObject.java:287)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:89)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
    at script(injected script:4)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:959)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:927)
    at Scraper.main(Scraper.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

The line causeing exception is:

```
Object result = page.executeJavaScript(script).getJavaScriptResult();
```

So how should I execute this script from HtmlUnit as I do from google chrome console?

Comment: @MostyMostacho could u help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are your `javascript` script errors translated to `Java exceptions` by your framework.

That's because you have not explicitly set the `setThrowExceptionOnScriptError` option of your `WebClient` to `false`.

Unless there are absolutely no errors in the `js`, it is useful to always set this value as false unless it interferes with the results your are looking for.

Typically, these are my `webclient` settings when dealing with `js` and `ajax` through `HtmlUnit`.

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17,
                PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL(
                "http://steamcommunity.com/id/bobcatchris/inventory#730"));

webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);

          String script="var list = [];\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "var size = Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory).size();\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "var counter = 0;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "while (counter < size) {\n" +
                    " list.push(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory[Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory)[counter]].market_name);\n" +
                    " counter +=1;\n" +
                    "}";
            Object result = page.executeJavaScript(script).getJavaScriptResult();
            System.out.println(result);
```

If I try your code, with the above settings I get `150.0` printed to the console which I assume is working as expected.

**EDIT:**

To traverse over the complete array `list`:

```
String script="var list = [];\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "var size = Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory).size();\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "var counter = 0;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "while (counter < size) {\n" +
                    " list.push(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory[Object.keys(g_ActiveInventory.rgInventory)[counter]].market_name);\n" +
                    " counter +=1;\n" +
                    "}"
                    + "list";

            Object result = page.executeJavaScript(script).getJavaScriptResult();
            if (result instanceof NativeArray) {
                for (Object obj : (NativeArray)result) {
                    System.out.println(obj);    
                }

            }
```

Above, I have change the `js` to include list as the return parameter and iterate over `NativeArray` to get each element.

**Output:**

```
P2000 | Scorpion (Factory New)
AK-47 | Black Laminate (Field-Tested)
★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Case Hardened (Minimal Wear)
CS:GO Case Key
CS:GO Case Key
```

You can read much on their ajax settings at their FAQs - [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork).

Comment: Can u please paste your code by which you executed javascript? I can not find something like executeJavascript() with the request object.

Comment: @rahulserver updated with the complete code, it's on the `HtmlPage` instance which in turn is created via the request

Comment: @rahulserver you can get the array in the same way as you get 150.0, I get the list as the last item in javascript and work it to get all the values - see the edit.